# How to get install gulp-protractor and set up standalone selenium server in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, selenium, gulp-protractor

I run `npm install gulp-protractor --save-dev` to install protractor and its requirements in my project.

According to this documentation(https://github.com/mllrsohn/gulp-protractor), I should find `'./node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar'`. But after I installed everything, that `selenium-server-standalone-xxx.jar` file is nowhere to be found. Even after I run `npm install protractor`, it don't shows up.

Here's my files at `node_modules/protractor`

[image]

What am I missing here?
I use Linux Ubuntu 16.04, node 6.9.1(via nvm)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the webdriver, you can find the instruction from this link
https://github.com/angular/protractor#appendix-a-setting-up-a-standalone-selenium-server